# How to generate a QR Code model 2 on Adafruit Magtag?

Tags: adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I purchased a Adafruit Magtag which is a board with an ESP32-S2 chipset and a 2.9" grayscale E-Ink display, I would like to generate a QR Code Model 2, but it does not appear the Magtag QR Code library supports this model of QR Code, or I am missing something.

Does anyone maybe have some suggestions or more experience, need a bit of a steer in the right direction, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but the main reason you might want to use Model 2 is that the QR code would be distorted on a curved surface. The E-ink display on the MagTag isn't curved. https://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/model12.html